# How to pull changes from the remote repository without pushing the local changes with Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Hi guys,

I am trying to use Github Desktop but I can't find on their website how to pull changes from the remote repository without pushing all the local changes. On github website, it is written :

> Pull changes — Click the “Sync” button in the upper-right corner of
>   GitHub Desktop to bring code from an online repository (for example,
>   changes that your co-worker pushed up) onto your computer. **Note: This
>   will also push changes you haven’t pushed yet.**

There's also a "Pull Requests" button on Github Desktop, but apparently it merges remote branches, which is definitely not what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a solution for the macOS version of Github Desktop.**

I had not explored Github Desktop enough..

We can achieve to pull changes from remote repository without pushing changes from local repository by selecting from the top bar menu :

Repository -> Pull

Or simply typing the shortcut:

Shift + Cmd + P

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work on the Windows version (answer probably refers to the Mac version).

Comment: Oh yes, I just edited my answer, feel free to post you solution here if you find one.